# Jenkins NodeJSPlugin node command not found

Tags: jenkins

The build shell is:

```
echo $PATH
which node
ls -l /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node_6.10.2/bin
node -v
```

The result is:

```
/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node_6.10.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node_6.10.2/bin/node
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jenkins jenkins 30503659 Apr  4 09:01 node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins       38 Apr  9 13:09 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/tmp/hudson8026342196338345661.sh: line 1: node: not found
```

Why cannot it find the node command?

I'm running it with docker the official jenkins image.

EDIT: jenkins:2.46.1-alpine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in [issue JENKINS-34815 (NodeJS plugin unable to install global NPM packages)](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34815), check you `ldd -l /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node_6.10.2/bin/node`

See [this comment](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34815?focusedCommentId=285315&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-285315):

> With current docker jenkins:2.32.1-alpine and plugin nodejs:1.0 this happens again, when using node 7.4:
> Alpine just can't run the binary even if it is found in PATH and is executable:

```
+ /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs7/bin/node -v

/var/jenkins_home/jobs/busx1/workspace@tmp/durable-a76d6fd5/script.sh: line 1: /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs7/bin/node: not found
```

> This happens because the image doesn't contain `libstdc++.so.6` as needed by nodejs:

```
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x55ae0ad53000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x55ae0ad53000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x55ae0ad53000)

Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs7/bin/node)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x55ae0ad53000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7f0ac773e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x55ae0ad53000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x55ae0ad53000)
```

In other words, `node: not found` does not mean `node` is not installed (it is, it is executable and found in the `$PATH`).
It means one of `node` dependencies is not found.

Comment: Should I not using alpine or install libstdc++.so.6 myself?

Comment: @hbrls The jenkins image is based on alpine already. All I am saying is that your image might be missing some elements. An `ldd -l` should tell you which one. If you see them missing, you will need to build your own image based on your existing image `jenkins:2.46.1-alpine`, to add the missing element.

Comment: So whats the solution here ? How to fix the "node not found" issue in alpine ?
I'm using Jenkins ver. 2.176.1 alpine and I have the same issue.

Comment: @JeraldSabuM I don't fully remember, but I suspect adding the missing dependency(ies) would be enough

Comment: @VonC How do i know, what dependency to install?  (ldd -l gives error)   :::---                                           

11:56:21  + ldd -l /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_10.19.0/bin/node
11:56:21  ldd: cannot load -l: No such file or directory

Comment: @JeraldSabuM Not sure: I would advise to ask a new separate question, with a link back to this answer, and  a lot of details specific to your current problem.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Your answer helped me in resolving dependencies, however node was still not executable hence I raised another question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539480/nodejs-with-jenkins-plugin-not-executable-in-alpine-image-and-displays-symbol-n

Comment: @JeraldSabuM OK, I will follow that question.

Answer (score 1):

I run the Jenkins by a docker image jenkins:2.60.3-alpine.

And I've solved this by entering the container then install node directly:

You can find your container name using:

```
$ docker container ls
```

then replace with  with the real name of container,

```
$ docker exec -u 0 -it <container_name> bash

bash-4.3# apk add --no-cache nodejs
bash-4.3# node --version
v6.9.5
bash-4.3# npm --version
5.6.0
```

Finally, the job could use the node and npm both.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The problem here is with alpine and Jenkins nodejs plugin. There's no issue in installing nodejs directly in alpine docker.

Comment: apk-get for alpine version dockers, but ubuntu based you should use apt-get for debian bases.